# How to change yticks in the seaborn.distplot() from normalised values to absolute values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, gaussian, curve

I am trying to create a gaussian curve (without the bar charts) using the `seaborn.displot()` method. Unfortunately, I get normalised values on the y-axis instead of the absolute values. How can I resolve this issue?

Here's my code:

```
height_mu = 165
height_sigma = 15
heights = np.random.normal(height_mu, height_sigma, size=10000)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
sns.distplot(heights, hist=False)
plt.axvline(165, color='red', label='Mean height (in cm)', linewidth=2)
plt.ylabel("Number of observations")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(which='major', axis='y', color='lightgrey')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what do you mean by normalised values on the y-axis? that is the frequency of occurrence of the values in `heights`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option inside seaborn to revert to counts, because once kde is turned on, the `norm_hist` option is `False`. Strictly speaking, when a gaussian kernel is applied, you get the density whose values depends on the binwidth and [it can be >1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5819/kernel-density-estimate-takes-values-larger-than-1).

To get something similar to counts, you need to first define the bin width (sns.displot does it for you) and use `gaussian_kde` to perform the density. The values are density and you convert by multiplying the density values by binwidth and number of observations, e.g `counts_i = n * dens_i * binwidth`

As noted by @mwaskom(see comments), may not be the best to show just the kde plot with y-axis as counts.

We can check this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(999)
height_mu = 165
height_sigma = 15
heights = np.random.normal(height_mu, height_sigma, size=10000)
nbins = 50

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(10, 4))
sns.distplot(heights, hist=True,norm_hist=False,kde=False,bins=nbins,ax=ax[0])
sns.distplot(heights, hist=False,bins=nbins,ax=ax[1])
ax[1].axvline(165, color='red', label='Mean height (in cm)', linewidth=2)

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
dens = gaussian_kde(heights)
xlen,step = np.linspace(heights.min(),heights.max(),num=nbins,retstep=True)
ax[2].plot(xlen,len(heights)*dens(xlen)*step)
ax[2].axvline(165, color='red', label='Mean height (in cm)', linewidth=2)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

The first plot on the left, you have the histogram with counts, 2nd plot the density plot you have, and on the right, the density with the "counts".

Comment: This is a good solution for putting a kde over a histogram with counts in the y axis but it's important to emphasize that the right panel is not "absolute" in any sense. The scale of the y axis depends entirely on the histogram binwidth, and I don't think it makes any sense to plot a density curve with a count y axis without showing the histogram bins that lead to those counts.

Comment: @mwaskom, thank you for the comment. Yes I agree with you a density curve with counts doesn't make sense, because a kde can only give you density. I guess for presentation purposes people try to switch between these. I will update my post with your points.

Comment: To be clear, I've come around on putting a KDE over a histogram and keeping the y axis in counts; this will be in the next release of seaborn. But having *just* the kde, and a y axis in counts, does not make sense IMO.

Comment: Bang on! The counts on the y-axis are to be displayed only for the presentation purposes. Apparently, non-academic business people are not too comfortable with the KDEs. Nevertheless, thanks for the help!